# Calculate unique data jumps using Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a time series data frame df1 like this:

```
DateTime      Power[HP]  PowerJump   PowerStart
01/01/2018    0          0           0
01/02/2018    10         0           1
01/03/2018    99         1           0
01/04/2018    20         0           0
01/05/2018    60         0           0
01/06/2018    70         0           0
01/07/2018    15         0           0
01/08/2018    95         1           0
01/09/2018    0          0           0
01/10/2018    10         0           1
01/11/2018    0          0           0
01/12/2018    95         1           1
```

Power Jump tags cases where power increased at least 20HP to 90HP or more.
Power Starts tags every case where engine started producing power.

Now I would like to count cycles where cycle is either power production start or power jump. When power start is followed by the power jump it is counted as one.

[image]

There are 4 cycles in total for this data sample.

This is the expected output:

```
DateTime      Power[HP]  PowerJump   PowerStart  Cycle
01/01/2018    0          0           0           0
01/02/2018    10         0           1           1
01/03/2018    99         1           0           0
01/04/2018    20         0           0           0
01/05/2018    60         0           0           0
01/06/2018    70         0           0           0
01/07/2018    15         0           0           0
01/08/2018    95         1           0           1
01/09/2018    0          0           0           0
01/10/2018    10         0           1           1
01/11/2018    0          0           0           0
01/12/2018    95         1           1           1
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please provide your expected result?

Which will be more clear for us to help you

Thanks
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out.
My code:

```
df1.loc[0,'Cycle']=0
j = True
    
for i in range (1, len(df1)):            
    if df1.loc[i,'Power[HP]']!=0 and df1.loc[i-1,'Power[HP]']==0:
        df1.loc[i,'Cycle'] = 1
        j = False
    else:                
        if j == True:
            if df1.loc[i,'Power[HP]']>=90 and (df1.loc[i,'Power[HP]']-df1.loc[i-1, 'Power[HP]']>=20):
                df1.loc[i,'Cycle'] = 1  
            else:
                df1.loc[i,'Cycle'] = 0
        else:
            df1.loc[i,'Cycle'] = 0
            if df1.loc[i,'Power[HP]']>df1.loc[i-1,'Power[HP]']:
                j = False
            else:
                j = True
```